# replacement error when feeding data from function into matrix in R

Tags: r, error, matrix, function

I am trying to write a function that creates simulated datasets.

The function takes the argument size, being the size of a group, and it is meant to produce a matrix with 100 columns with values 0 or 1, ranging from 1 to 100%, i.e, in the first column, 1% of "size" is "1" and 99% if "size" is "0" and in column ten, 10% of "size" is "1" and 90% if "size" is "0" and so on.

```
create.group <- function(size) {
  group<-data.frame(matrix( nrow=size, ncol = 100))
  for (i in 1:100) {
    group[,i] <-sample(c(rep(1, (i*size/100)), rep(0, (size-(i*size/100)))))
  }
  group
}

create.group(100)
```

Now, the function does exactly what I want, as long as "size" is a multiple of 100, but any other number leads to an error, e.g. for size = 150

"*Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  :
replacement has 149 rows, data has 150"

Sorry, probably a daft question, but if someone could give me a hint on where I went wrong, it would be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the second argument of the *rep* function is not an integer, the function rounds it down and proceeds with the *floor* of the initial value. Consequently, for $i=1$, because the fraction $$\frac{i*size}{100}$$ is not an integer unless *size* is a multiple of $100$, one has less than one hundred entries to feed the first column of the matrix...

You may want to try this instead:

```
                       create.group <- function(size) {
                             group<-data.frame(matrix( nrow=size, ncol = 100))
                             for (i in 1:100) {
                                  group[,i] <-sample(c(rep(1, floor((i*size/100))), 
                                                       rep(0, ceiling((size-(i*size/100))))))
                             }
                             return(group)
                       }
```

Comment: Great, that solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!!!

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes!